# Converting an XML from GCS Blob storage to String not working for special characters

Tags: java, json, xml, string, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to read the contents of a gcs bucket and parse the XML files that might be there.
It is working fine except that characters that are not Latin alphabet (Chinese, Japanese etc.) are being converted into various erroneous symbols.

First I get my storage list :

```
   Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(
                bucketName,
                Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(bucketLocation),
                Storage.BlobListOption.currentDirectory()
        );
```

Then I iterate through the blobs and parse each that matches the type of file I am looking for (XML). In my parseXML method I do:

```
 byte[] fileByteContent = blob.getContent();
 String blobContent = new String(fileByteContent, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
 JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(blobContent);
```

However my JSONObject will display nonsense for special characters, for example this field which is in hebrew:

```
Source:
עם פרסום דוחות רווח
Output:
×¢× ×¤×¨×¡×•× ×“×•×—×•×ª ×¨
```

What am I missing? I have added the UTF_8 Charset definition in the string parsing, does it need to be considered somewhere else?

Comment: Have you tried using `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` based on this [documentation](StandardCharsets.UTF_8)? Your code should appear like this: `String blobContent = new String(fileByteContent, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`.

Comment: Actually I am, I didn't include it but I am using `import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8` which is where I am getting the UTF_8 from.

Comment: Apologies as I haven't included the link. Let me know if you find this link ([Encoding With Core Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-encode-utf-8#core-java)) helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your info that you read is partially lost (corrupted). I tried to restore it and the best I got was:

```
×¢× ×¤×¨×¡×•× ×“×•×—×•×ª ×¨ // your data
×ע× ×פ×ר×ס×•× ×“×•×—×•×ת ×ר  // my attempt at extraction
```

comparing with what you expected in Hebrew:

```
עם פרסום דוחות רווח
```

You can see that some of the letters in Hebrew are restored in correct positions. But some are lost or at least I can not see the logic how to restore it. The way I did the check I converted your data to Unicode sequences and also the Hebrew string to Unicode sequences. Here is what I got:

```
×¢× ×¤×¨×¡×•× ×“×•×—×•×ª ×¨
\u00d7\u00a2\u00d7\u0020\u00d7\u00a4\u00d7\u00a8\u00d7\u00a1\u00d7\u2022\u00d7\u0020\u00d7\u201c\u00d7\u2022\u00d7\u2014\u00d7\u2022\u00d7\u00aa\u0020\u00d7\u00a8
עם פרסום דוחות רווח
\u05e2\u05dd\u0020\u05e4\u05e8\u05e1\u05d5\u05dd\u0020\u05d3\u05d5\u05d7\u05d5\u05ea\u0020\u05e8\u05d5\u05d5\u05d7
```

I noticed that all the Hebrew letters that are encoded with "05e*" have corresponding code "00a*" (see the first letter "ע" code 05e2 for example corresponds to code 00a2). However all the Hebrew letters with codes 05d* seem to be lost. To do the conversions I used class `StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder` that comes from Open Source library MgntUtils written and maintained by me. Here is the code in case you would like to play with it more:

```
        String testStr1 = "×¢× ×¤×¨×¡×•× ×“×•×—×•×ª ×¨";
//        testStr1 = "¢ ¤¨¡• “•—•ª ¨";
        String encoded1 = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(testStr1);
//        encoded1 = encoded1.replaceAll("0a", "5e");
        String restored = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(encoded1);
        System.out.println(testStr1 + "\n" + encoded1 + "\n" + restored);
        testStr1 = "עם פרסום דוחות רווח";
        encoded1 = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(testStr1);
        restored = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(encoded1);
        System.out.println(testStr1 + "\n" + encoded1 + "\n" + restored);
```

Here is [Javadoc for StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html). The MgntUtils library could be obtained as [Maven Artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or on The [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases)